# Задача по строкам javascript

Tags: javascript

Задача:

Создай функцию countMs, которая принимает строку text и возвращает количество букв m в ней (и больших и маленьких вместе).

```
1)Создай переменную count
2)Создай цикл for of, который будет перебирать каждый символ в text
На каждой итерации проверяй, равен ли текущий символ 'm' или 'M': если это так, увеличивай count на 1
3) Создать через перебор по символам.
```

мой печальный код. бьюсь уже сутки с этой задачкой

```
function countMs(text) {
  const count = text;

  for (const letter of count) {
   
  }
 return count;
}
```

Comment: Однострочный вариант без явных циклов: `const countMs = text => text.split(/m/i).length - 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без отедльной проверки на каждый размер буквы. Сразу делаем любой символ маленьким и проверяем:

```js
const countMs = (text) => {
  let count = 0;

  for (const letter of text) {
    if (letter.toLowerCase() === 'm') ++count;
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(countMs("Hellom woMrld!"))
```

Можно пойти чуть дальше и сделать более обобщённый метод для поиска любой буквы без учёта регистра:

```js
const countMs = (text, targetLetter) => {
  let count = 0;

  for (const letter of text) {
    if (letter.toLowerCase() === targetLetter.toLowerCase()) ++count;
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(countMs('Hellom woMrld!', 'm'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countMs(text) {
    let count = 0;
    for (const letter of text) 
        if(letter == 'm' || letter == 'M') count++;
    return count;
}

console.log(countMs("Hellom woMrld!"))
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В вашем коде было 3 ошибки:
1. Объявили переменную 'count' с типом данных 'const', который не изменяется.
2. Присвоили переменной 'count' 'text'.
3. В цикле шли по 'count', нужно по 'text'

Comment: благодарочка бро!) я не мог понять как сравнение поставить правильно, спасибо за помощь!